# Feasibility of recreating complex SQL query in Crystal Reports XI

Tags: t-sql, crystal-reports-xi

I have about 10 fairly complex SQL queries on SQL Server 2008 - but the client wants to be able to run them from their internal network (as opposed to from the non-local web app) through Crystal Reports XI.

The client's internal network does not allow us to (a) have write access to their proprietary db, nor (b) allow us to set up an intermediary SQL server (meaning we can not set up stored procedures or other data cleaning).

The SQL contains multiple instances of *row_number() over (partition by col1, col2)*, *group by col1, col2 with cube|rollup*, and/or (multiple) pivots.

Can this even be done? Everything I've read seems to indicate that this is only feasible via stored procedure and I would still need to pull the data from the proprietary db first.

Following is a stripped back version of one of the queries (eg, JOINs not directly related to functionality, WHERE clauses, and half a dozen columns have been removed)...

```
select sum(programID)
    , sum([a.Asian]) as [Episodes - Asian], sum([b.Asian]) as [Eps w/ Next Svc - Asian], sum([c.Asian])/sum([b.Asian]) as [Avg Days to Next Svc - Asian]
    , etc... (repeats for each ethnicity)
from (
    select programID, 'a.' + ethnicity as ethnicityA, 'b.' + ethnicity as ethnicityB, 'c.' + ethnicity as ethnicityC
        , count(*) as episodes, count(daysToNextService) as episodesWithNextService, sum(daysToNextService) as daysToNextService
    from (
        select programID, ethnicity, datediff(dateOfDischarge, nextDateOfService) as daysToNextService from (
            select t1.userID, t1.programID, t1.ethnicity, t1.dateOfDischarge, t1.dateOfService, min(t2.dateOfService) as nextDateOfService
            from TABLE1 as t1 left join TABLE1 as t2
                on datediff(d, t1.dateOfService, t2.dateOfService) between 1 and 31 and t1.userID = t2.userID
            group by t1.userID, t1.programID, t1.ethnicity, t1.dateOfDischarge, t1.dateOfService
        ) as a
    ) as a
    group by programID
) as a
pivot (
    max(episodes) for ethnicityA in ([A.Asian],[A.Black],[A.Hispanic],[A.Native American],[A.Native Hawaiian/ Pacific Isl.],[A.White],[A.Unknown])
) as pA
pivot (
    max(episodesWithNextService) for ethnicityB in ([B.Asian],[B.Black],[B.Hispanic],[B.Native American],[B.Native Hawaiian/ Pacific Isl.],[B.White],[B.Unknown])
) as pB
pivot (
    max(daysToNextService) for ethnicityC in ([C.Asian],[C.Black],[C.Hispanic],[C.Native American],[C.Native Hawaiian/ Pacific Isl.],[C.White],[C.Unknown])
) as pC
group by programID with rollup
```

Sooooooo.... can something like this even be translated into Crystal Reports XI?

Thanks!

Comment: If they don't have access to the data from their internal network how will they be running the report?

Comment: They do; up until now, they've exported their proprietary db on a weekly basis to our web app.

Comment: how do you know that advanced SQL techniques will even work against their proprietary db? THe advanced techniques tend to be database sepcific.

Comment: That is _exactly_ the reason I'm trying to find out if this can even be translated to Crystal Reports. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your report instead of selecting a table or stored procedure choose `add command`

This will allow you to put whatever valid TSQL statement in there that you want. Using Common Table Expressions (CTE's) and inline Views I've managed to create some rather large complex statements (excess of 400 lines) against Oracle and SQL Server so it is indeed feasible, however if you use parameters <strike>you should consider using `sp_executesql`</strike> you'll have to figure out how to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Do you know if this is simply transmitting the command to the db server? The back-end is accessible only via ODBC and is not an MSSQL or Oracle server - and so will not be able to process the T-SQL on its own. This needs to happen on the Crystal Reports server.

Comment: Yes the command will be sent to the DB Server and executed there and returned to the report. BTW Since you tagged it as TSQL is this Sybase?

Comment: I don't have any information on their back-end, except that it's some sort of proprietary system. I tagged it as TSQL because that's what I wrote the original queries in (that run against our exported version of the db).

Comment: well its still feasible as long as the DB allows for inline views (I don't know of any that don't) but avoiding SQL injection may be cause for concern.

Comment: I did get some more information on the back-end; it doesn't appear to support `ROLLUP`, `CUBE`, or `row_number()` so without that functionality in Crystal Reports, this looks to be a dead project. I'm marking your answer as correct - I appreciate your assistance!